# Joomla component function deprecated

Tags: php

I am using a Joomla component `com_fabrik` but though its install successfully. As I try to create form I am getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setId() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sankalpJoomla\administrator\components\com_fabrik\models\form.php on line 108
```

When I searched for code in file I got.

```
$feFormModel->setId($this->getState('form.id'));
```

I searched that function is deprecated. is their any other option to sort out problem?

Answer (score 0):

While it may be that the function is deprecated, the error you're getting isn't related to that (at least not directly). What is happening is `$feFormModel` isn't an actual object, and because of that it has *no* memeber functions. So when `setId()` is being called from it, this error is being thrown.

The likely cause is some sort of incompatibility between this component and the version of Joomla you're using.